# Improper integral of $\int_1^2 \frac{\sqrt{x}}{\log(x)}\,\mathrm dx$

Tags: definite-integrals, improper-integrals, gamma-function

The question is to check the convergence of the  improper integral of  $\int_1^2 \frac{\sqrt{x}}{\log(x)}\,\mathrm dx$. I tried using comparision test and tried to convert or compare it to the Gamma function but it led to nowhere .

Comment: your integral doesn't converge on the given interval

Comment: Your function doesn't seem to have an elementary primitive.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Sorry made a typo in the question . Fixed it now . How did you prove it is diverging ?

Comment: The integral is divergent.

Comment: @ArchisWelankar Yes but how though ?

Comment: Do you know $Ei (x) $ ?

Comment: @ArchisWelankar No

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\int_1^2 \frac{\sqrt{x}}{\log(x)}\,\mathrm dx\geq\int_1^2 \frac{1}{x\log(x)}\,\mathrm dx\to+\infty$$

Comment: One relevant detail here is that $\log \log x$ is the antiderivative of $1/(x \log x)$, and that $\log \log x \to - \infty$ as $x \downarrow 1$.

Comment: No. $x\log x>0$.

Comment: I am talking about $\log \log x$.

Comment: @MyGlasses Shalop is correct.

Comment: @RobertZ It's realy $-\log\log x\to+\infty$, Furthermore when the integrand is positive how it's integral will be negative!

Comment: @MyGlasses I agree. Anyway Shalop's comment is correct.

Answer (score 0):

We compare the integrand with the function $1/(x-1)$. Note that 
$$\lim_{x\to 1^+}\frac{\sqrt{x}(x-1)}{\ln(x)}=\lim_{t\to 0^+}\frac{t}{\ln(1+t)}=1$$
which implies that there is $r\in (1,2]$ such that for all $x\in (1,r]$
$$\frac{\sqrt{x}(x-1)}{\ln(x)}\geq \frac{1}{2}\implies \frac{\sqrt{x}}{\ln(x)}\geq \frac{1}{2(x-1)}.$$
Therefore 
$$\int_1^2\frac{\sqrt{x}}{\ln(x)}\, dx\geq \frac{1}{2}\int_1^r\frac{1}{x-1}\,d x=\frac{1}{2}\left(\ln(r-1)-\lim_{x\to 1^+}\ln(x-1)\right)=+\infty.$$